# Is it possible to set a currency per user?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to set a currency per user rather than based on a user's address. So that no matter where in the world a customer was looking at the site they would always see their "home" price? e.g a US based customer always sees the $ price, even if they are currently shopping from Europe.

Ideal solution would be to have a currency selection box in the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Check this WooCommerce Plugin: "The **Currency Converter Widget** lets you offer a dynamic currency switcher for displaying product prices and totals." "... your customers will be able to change the currency". (It costs extra, though.)

https://woocommerce.com/products/currency-converter-widget/

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/handle-multiple-regions-currencies-woocommerce/

**Option 2**

Another plugin. **WooCommerce Multi-Currency**: "Multi-Currency is a WooCommerce extension that provides switching currencies and re-calculating rates on-the-fly." The user can "Choose the currency using a sidebar widget" and "Pay in the selected currency" (Also costs extra.)

https://woocommerce.com/products/multi-currency/

Here is an overview on the topic:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shop-currency/ -> text on Multiple Currencies

Comment: Hi Jasie, thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I don’t want the user to be able to switch currency. I want to set it for them so that if they are a $ paying customer for example they always see the fixed $ price even if they are shopping from a different country to their ‘home’ country.

Comment: You could write your own WordPress plugin. But how should this work? If a user wants to become a customer, he has to register? And this registration is blocked until you set the currency for that user? How do you know in what currency the customer usually pays? What about countries having more than one usual currency?

Comment: My customer base is very small and to view the products requires a login (which I provide) for each user after they request one so the ability is there for me to set that currency before they ever view the products part of the website.